# Ordinal scale: does aggregating data by arithmetic mean is a concrete problem?

Tags: statistics, data-analysis, means

Sometimes when people have some ordinal values, they use a misleading number representation. Then, they aggregate data with arithmetic mean. For example, we have to aggregate the grades of an exam evaluated by an ordinal scale: Excellent,...,Very Poor. Sometimes people do this mapping:

5 - Excellent,
4 - Very Good,
3 - Good,
2 - Poor,
1 - Very Poor.

Then they say "The arithmetic mean is 3". besides they compare that mean with means of other previous exam. But that is an ordinal scale, we cannot do a mean!

Ok, formally it is not correct but what are the concrete problems of using a mean for ordinal values? Might be some kind of rank reversal while comparing different average values?

Comment: Whether it causes concrete/practical problems depends on the application. There is nothing wrong with saying the average grade was 4.2 (schools do it all the time). If people agree with the mapping, then there is no issue. I would say the only issue is if you try to extend beyond talking about grades to actual performance. Did a person who got a 4 really do twice as well as a person who got a 2?

Comment: Exactly, you got the point! The problem is on the mapping. When someone maps a very good to 3 and a poor to 1, he is assuming that getting _very good_ is equal to two times getting _poor_. That's the misconception. I don't know if there are practical real life problem arising from that...

Comment: In education research, a Likert mapping seems quite common and unproblematic. Think about GPA's....they are used all the time, but is getting an A really twice as good as getting a C, especially if they are from different courses?